# cURL returns a relative "Location:" url, how to get the full URL?

Tags: php, redirect, curl, http-status-code-301, http-status-code-302

I'm using cURL in order to bypass redirections (301, 302) and special URLs like `adf.ly` and such. I have a working code but I couldn't fix this specific problem:

When I'm using cURL to follow the `location` parameter, on some websites, the last redirection may have a relative url in its `Location:` result.

To make it clear, I added such redirection in my own website. I'm using

```
header("Location: /maintenance"); exit();
```

in my PHP code in order to demonstrate it. I made this quick cURL request:

```
$url = "http://deci.deals/post/99/comment/427";

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1712.4 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
$data = curl_exec( $ch );
curl_close($ch);

echo("<br/>CURRENT_URL: ".$url);

if ( preg_match_all( '/Location:\s*(.+)\s*$/im', $data, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER ) ) {
    $last = array_pop( $matches );
    echo "<br/>FOUND: ".$last[1];
}
```

The output:

```
CURRENT_URL: http://deci.deals/post/99/comment/427
FOUND: /maintenance
```

As you can see, the `Location` value is a relative URL. Is there any way to get the absolute URL instead of this?

Thanks!

Comment: echo curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);

Comment: @Robot70 thanks! is it safe to trust this URL instead of the `Location` result?

Comment: I dunno. That's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

From [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location) Wikipedia page:

> Relative URLs are URLs that do not include a scheme or a host. In
>   order to be understood they must be combined with the URL of the
>   original request.
>
> Client request for http://www.example.com/blog:

```
GET /blog HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
```

> Server response:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: /articles/
```

> The URL of the location is expanded by the client to

```
http://www.example.com/articles/
```

Comment: I was thinking about connecting them, but I think that `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` might "jump" a redirection ahead and then it will me impossible to rely the original URL, correct me if I'm wrong